# What's the best way to get started with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: purchasing

I've always been interested in technology trying new programs/games, tinking with a few mediocre languages, and been learning a big one for a while now at college. However, I've longed to get into Raspberry Pi's and I wonder where I should start.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad and opinion based. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. You may visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start at the [MagPi Magazine](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/) there's lots of projects to try. Everything from the MagPi Mag is available as a free download or can be purchased printed on pulped dead trees.

Getting a Raspberry is easy, you need a RPi3B+, an official power supply, an official keyboard & mouse and a HDMI cable to connect it to your TV.

Something like the [ModMyPi ultimate kit](https://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/set-up-kits/rpi3-model-b-plus-kits/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus-kit-build-your-own-ultimate) may be an easy way to get all the parts in a single bundle {Note: I am not affiliated to ModMyPi in any way}

Comment: Are all projects, in the magazines, on https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en @Dougie?

Comment: @AlienDrew I don't think so. Projects.raspberrypi.org is a fairly new addition. The MagPi (originally an end-user created magazine) has been running a lot longer.

Comment: Would you say the magazine has better projects than the link then?

Comment: Having been part of the original editting team I'm biased. I think the projects books are a good starting point for everyone. The benefit of the magazine is you're getting something new every month. You'll also get a Raspberry Zero (or 3A+) if you take a subscription.

Answer (score 4):

You need

- the latest Raspberry Pi 3+
- an microSD card
- an micro-USB powersupply (2100 mA or more)

Click on the official "Buy now" link [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/). After that, have a look at the (extensive) materials, worksheets, projects and documentation here:

https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/pathways/getting-started-with-raspberry-pi

The Raspberry Pi website is full of materials for teachers, schoolchildren and everybody else who wants to learn programming, physical computing and much more with the Pi :

https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en

Comment: Does the link have better projects than the MagPi magazine?

Comment: I think they are just different. The projects on the homepage probably better structured for classroom use.